# Sorting values of a selectable month

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A               B        C           D                   E    
1                   January    February     March              February
2    Product A        500        300         800                 500
3    Product B        400        500         250                 300
4    Product C        600        100         700                 100
```

In **Columns A:C** you can see the sales of three different products.
In **Column E** the user can select a month in **Cell E1**.
Based on this month the sales should be listed ascending.

I think this requires something like a **VLOOKUP** combined with a **LARGE** function since the matrix from the LARGE function has to switch based on the month in **Cell E1**.

Do you have any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HLOOKUP to locate the month in E1 in the range B1:D1, but this just gives the value of the month ("February") and you need the position of the month (from 1 to 3) to find the right column B,C or D so I suggest using Index and Match as follows

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,0,MATCH($E$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

[image]